# How can I add background color to odd element which has specific class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to add background color to odd elements which has `.row` class in the wrapper element. But another div comes after each .row element so when I add `nth-child(odd)` selector, background color of all `.row` elements changes. How can I add with only css?

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

.row {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.description {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">Row-1</div>
  <div class="description">Description-1</div>
  <div class="row">Row-2</div>
  <div class="description">Description-2</div>
  <div class="row">Row-3</div>
  <div class="description">Description-3</div>
  <div class="row">Row-4</div>
  <div class="description">Description-4</div>
  <div class="row">Row-5</div>
  <div class="description">Description-5</div>
</div>
```

[JsBin Example](https://jsbin.com/yobicesoni/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, if you know perfectly there will be another coming in, out of the even elements, you need to find the even ones. You need to use `:nth-child()` in a different way:

```css
.row:nth-child(4n + 1) {}
```

This will select the even items of the even elements.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

.row {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.description {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">Row-1</div>
  <div class="description">Description-1</div>
  <div class="row">Row-2</div>
  <div class="description">Description-2</div>
  <div class="row">Row-3</div>
  <div class="description">Description-3</div>
  <div class="row">Row-4</div>
  <div class="description">Description-4</div>
  <div class="row">Row-5</div>
  <div class="description">Description-5</div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: But, it seems to be exactly the same result as OP already have, isn't it?

Comment: @CalvinNunes Looks like I made a mistake! Wait...

Comment: @CalvinNunes I am so sorry, I have fixed it. Thanks for bringing it up! 

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your markup setup, you would need to target every 4th div element within `.wrapper`:

```
.row:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: red;
}
```

Keep in mind that this is not flexible, so if you add divs it will disrupt your desired effect of odd numbered `.row` divs.